# Por que al hacer clic en un poligono siempre realiza la misma accion - Google maps API android app

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps

Tengo 3 poligonos dentro de un mismo mapa creado en la aplicacion android

```
Polygon nordOption = mMap.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
        .add(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10,p11,p12,p13,p14,p15,p16,p17,p18,p19,p20,p21,p22,p23,p24,p25,p26,p27,p28,p29,p30,p31,p32,p33,p34,p35,p36,p37,p38,p39,p40,p41)
        .strokeColor(Color.RED));

Polygon centreOption = mMap.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
  .add(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12,c13,c14,c15,c16,c17,c18,c19,c20,c21,c22,c23,c24)
    .strokeColor(Color.BLUE));

Polygon sudOption = mMap.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
.add(s1,s2,s3,s4,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10,s11,s12,s13,s14)
.strokeColor(Color.GREEN));
```

cada uno tiene activado el click listener

```
nordOption.setClickable(true);
centreOption.setClickable(true);
sudOption.setClickable(true);
```

la idea es que al presionar cada poligono, realice una accion diferente, pero lo unico que he logrado es hacer la misma accion no importa que poligono le haga clic

```
mMap.setOnPolygonClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPolygonClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPolygonClick(Polygon polygon) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Soy centro",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para saber que poligono estamos cliqueando, solamente debemos de utilisar la propiedad del poligono "id", cada poligono tiene su propio id,para recuperar el id solamente usamos la funcion

```
.getId();
```

Codigo ejemplo

```
mMap.setOnPolygonClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPolygonClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPolygonClick(Polygon polygon) {

        String zone = polygon.getId();
        switch (zone){
            case "pg3":
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Nord",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case "pg4":
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Centr",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case "pg5":
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"sud",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }
    }
});
```